# Синхронизация в GWT

Tags: gwt, синхронизация, java

Поискал, но так и не понял, есть ли синхронизация в GWT? Имею в виду приостановку потока и запуск его при определенных условиях (события, критические секции и т.д.).

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам синхронизация в GWT? На клиенте нет никаких потоков, а на сервере уже есть всё готовое в самой яве.

Всё что можно сделать в GWT, это делать асинхронные вызовы на сервер (на самом деле AJAX), таймеры и отложенные операции (DeferredCommands), но все эти вещи (кроме асинхронного ввода-вывода) на самом деле построены на очереди событий, так что настоящих потоков в GWT на клиентской стороне вы нигде не найдёте. Я уж не говорю о критических секциях: они просто не имеют смысла.